# coin flip animation with HTML canvas rectangle

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am new to HTML Canvas and am trying to animate a simple square to perform X number of coin "flips" like the coin flip animation [here](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-sprite-animation/). I'm having a hard time understanding how to manipulate my square to produce this type of animation. Here's what I have so far. Can anyone show me how to coin "flip" a rectangle like this? Thanks.

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = 'red'
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 20, 20);

var percent = 0
var totalFlips = 10
var flips = 0
function animate() {
  if (percent++ < 100) {
    flips += 1
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  var width = 20 * percent / 100
  ctx.fillRect(percent, 0, width, 20);
}

animate()
```

Comment: You could make a CSS square and use 3D transformations

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately I need it to be in Canvas.

Comment: `perct` was probably meant to be `percent`. I'd recommend a [mcve] here; as it stands, your red rectangle grows, but it's not clear to me what that has to do with the coin flipping example. What do you mean by "coin flip a rectangle"?

Comment: You would increment an angle variable and multiply the width by the cosine of the angle.

Comment: Draw on the canvas, then flip the canvas?